# How to change user's default database using SQL for SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I tried:

```
ALTER LOGIN  user
WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = defaultDB
```

but it says:

> Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN'.

I know this works in 2005+ but is there a different way in 2000?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
exec sp_defaultdb @loginame='someone', @defdb='dbname'
```

Or since there are only those 2 parameters,

```
exec sp_defaultdb 'someone', 'dbname'
```

Comment: You are incredible, thanks. I was having problems with Navicat and DBComparer, they just couldn't connect to the database, because we removed the database that was related to the user we were using to log into the database server. Binding the user to an existing database fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Abe, the [`ALTER LOGIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) statement was introduced in `SQL Server 2005`, you must try using the [`sp_defaultdb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) stored procedure how @cyberkiwi suggest.